# apache http server and public IP

Tags: apache

I installed Apache HTTP server for running a Java Struts2 app. All ok when running as localhost but when I try to use public IP, nothing works
Apache is listening on port 80.
In the router configuration I forwarded port 80 on local address (the router address 192.168.0.1 but I also tried on computer address , i.e. 192.168.0.104)
I enabled traffic on this port on my (Norton) firewall (and also on Windows firewall although I think it's superfluous because Norton should disable it).
Where did I go wrong?
(I tried moreover to set in httpd.conf: ServerName realIP:80, NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.1, NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.104, NameVirtualHost realIP...)
Thanx in advance

PS - windows 7 pro as OS and Tomcat as AS therefore ajp13 as prot (but I think this does not matter)

Comment: It sounds like your apache is behind NAT and you're trying to give it the external network IP?

Comment: sorry but i'm completely ignorant in networking (I'm a java programmer and this is the first time I try to publish outside AS). Whats NAT?

Answer (score 0):

ok, now I am informed. I have no special needs on address translation. It's enough for me that those people (different and distant (to me and to each other)) who commissioned the work can remotely preview  the result. So all I need is my only one physical ip is accessible from the outside.

Comment: Thanx, I look around on portforward.com and it confirmed my setting was ok. Maybe I could sense of the problem but I completely unarmed to solve it! between my router and the net... there's still a modem!

Comment: sorry, I meant: there's even a modem! 
So:
- when I set a fixed IP to my PC I given the LAN IP address (i.e. 192.168.0.104)
- the classical subnet mask (which I've seen is the same on router and modem, 255.255.255.0) and 
- the default Gateway of the router (192.168.0.1)... or I should have given the modem defalult Gateway? ...or instead the modem IP address (10.0.0.1)? 
- As preferred and alternate DNS, instead, I given those of the modem (the real provided by ISP)...
What a confusion!

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a router, NAT is what the router does for you.  You just have to set it up once and give your public IP to others of set up dynamic update of your IP using DynDNS or some other provider.

Do not set public IP in Apache config. Instead, set your win 7 PC's IP there.  Thereafter, provide port forwarding on the router to the local IP you set in Apache configs.

IP/port forwarding settings differ based on different routers.    PortForward.com might be of help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I meant: there's even a modem! 
So:
 1. when I set a fixed IP to my PC I given the LAN IP address *(i.e. 192.168.0.104)*
 2. the classical subnet mask *(which I've seen is the same on router and modem, 255.255.255.0)* and
 3. the default Gateway of the router *(192.168.0.1)*... or I should have given the modem defalult Gateway? ...or instead the modem IP address *(10.0.0.1)*?
 4. As preferred and alternate DNS, instead, I given those of the modem *(the real provided by ISP)*...

What a confusion!

Comment: so it should be more clear! I regret having repeated the post in a question but I did not understand how to format a comment.

Comment: I apologize: in an answer

Comment: ...and moreover, what should be the _"local IP I set in Apache configs"_?

Comment: Thanks to all those who wanted to help me out: I already solved by myself!